# Put the {{$p_id}} on {{URL::to}} on blade view on laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, url-routing, laravel-blade

the below is work well

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default backurl"  data-href="{{URL::to('codo/a18/84')}}">
Go 
</button>
```

But I want to put the variable from the controller to the URL::to

```
{{$p_id}}=a18
{{$u_id}}=84
```

how can I write {{}} in {{}}

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default backurl"  data-href="{{URL::to('codo/{{$p_id}}/{{$u_id}}')}}">
Go 
</button>
```

I trid step by step

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default backurl"  data-href="{{URL::to('codo/{{$p_id}}/84')}}">
Go 
</button>
```

I got the error

```
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ')'"
```

on

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default backurl"  data-href="<?php echo e(URL::to('codo/{{$p_id); ?>/84')}}">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default backurl"  data-href="{{URL::to("codo/$p_id/$u_id')}}">
```

Actually you dont need to add braces again. `{{}}` this will compile to PHP and whatever you put in this will be treated as PHP.

```
{{" hello world"}} // is equal to <?php echo "hello world" ?>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve the problem.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default backurl"  data-href="{{URL::to('codo/' . $p_id . '/' . $u_id)}}">
Go 
</button>
```